# How can I set MasterPageFile for MasterPage dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, nested, master-pages

Can I define MasterPageFile for MasterPage from code?

I know how to do that for Page (OnPreInit event), but how to do that for MasterPage?
It does not contain OnPreInit event.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/582036/96505

Comment: Cool, it is good example, will check now...

Comment: @inser, I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Dynamically binding to a master page from a content page makes sense, but doing so from the master page does not, since the master page is the `.master` file itself.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I mean nested MasterPages